# Pandas str.rsplit doesn't work with logical or in the pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I tried to rsplit a string in Pandas, and got a strange result: split is working well, but rsplit is not. The reason seems to be the presence of OR "|", but I really struggle to understand why it is like this. 
Example:

```
stri = """Mywebsite.com/optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107?data=1.2. 1581202800. 1581289200.30"""
stri_1 = """optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107?data=1.2. 1581202800. 1581289200.30"""

df = pd.DataFrame({'input': [stri, stri_1]})
df_split1 = df['input'].str.split(r'\?data=', expand=True)
print(df_split1.loc[:, 0].str.rsplit(r'/|y', expand=True))
# |    | 0                                              |
# |---:|:-----------------------------------------------|
# |  0 | Mywebsite.com/optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107 |
# |  1 | optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107               |

print(df_split1.loc[:, 0].str.split(r'/|y', expand=True))
# |    | 0       | 1           | 2       | 3       | 4   | 5   |   6 |   7 |   8 |
# |---:|:--------|:------------|:--------|:--------|:----|:----|----:|----:|----:|
# |  0 | M       | website.com | optiona | optionb | t   | pe  | 102 | 103 | 107 |
# |  1 | optiona | optionb     | t       | pe      | 102 | 103 | 107 |     |     |
```

I guess this is due to some inherent left asymmetry of regexp, but I didn't find any good explanation.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [`Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) does not seem to support regex. It is said that it is *equivalent to `str.rsplit()`*

Comment: Pandas docs state otherwise: "pat: String or regular expression to split on".

Comment: Yep, I think this is buggy.

Comment: I think it `pd.Series.str.rsplit` should work just like `pd.Series.str.split`.  It is a reported bug....  [Open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29633)

Comment: Thank you, Scott! I was going crazy with this, really.